# How to configure .vimrc to make the autocomplete feature the some with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, brackets, sublimetext

I've found configure about autocompleting brackets,

```
inoremap ' ''<Left>
inoremap " ""<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap ( ()<Left>
```

but when I tried to delete the '(', the ')' stays, but in Sublime Text 2, that would disappear too. So how can I configure .vimrc ro make that?

// Update: got the vim-autoclose plugin, seems work now.

Comment: Why `imap ' <C-v>'<C-v>'<Left>` and not `inoremap ' ''<Left>`?

Comment: TOT , Mistake, I edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) you can do this by using

```
inoremap ' ''<Left>
inoremap " ""<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap ( ()<Left>

imap <expr> <C-h> "\<C-\>\<C-n>x".((col('.')==col('$'))?(""):("h"))."a"
imap <BS>  <C-h>
let s:pairsymbols={"'": "'",
            \      '"': '"',
            \      '{': '}',
            \      '(': ')',}
function! s:DelPair()
    let cnt=v:count1
    if col('$')==1
        let shiftline=(line('.')<line('$'))
        normal! dd
        if shiftline
            normal! k
        endif
        normal! $
        if cnt>1
            execute 'normal '.(cnt-1).'x'
        endif
        return
    endif
    let curch=getline('.')[col('.')-1]
    if has_key(s:pairsymbols, curch)
        let oldchtick=b:changedtick
        if getline('.')[col('.')] is# s:pairsymbols[curch]
            normal! 2x
        else
            execute "normal \<Plug>Dsurround".s:pairsymbols[curch]
            if b:changedtick==oldchtick
                normal! x
            endif
        endif
    else
        normal! x
    endif
    if cnt>1
        execute 'normal '.(cnt-1).'x'
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap x :<C-u>call <SID>DelPair()<CR>
```

Comment: someting strange. Typed a string with barackets suc as "(somthing)" in Vim, when tring to delete the word 'g' in the brackets, the curse jumped to the end rather than stay. That's confusing.

Comment: Thanks, but still a small bug. I opened a new line at the end of a txt file, then try to delete this empty line with Backspace, It jumps two lines back, rather than one. (This doesn't occur when it is not the last line.)

Comment: :) While deleting the brackets at the head of a line, it escapes the Insert mode; And tried open a new file, open new line with 'o', then type "func (", which gives out "func ()", while I tried to delete '(' with Backspace, the space in 'c ()' was deleted(but this works righltly in other situations).

Comment: while deleting in the last line with Backspace (which has indents before the curse), the curse jumps to the line above, rather than removing an indent.